# list of supersingular elliptic curves

Tags: elliptic-curves

Who can give me a table of supersingualr elliptic curves over F_p? At lsist for small p. If I make such a table using magma on my laptop, how long (as a function of p) will I use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $p \leq 307$ you can use [this table](http://wstein.org/Tables/antwerp/table6) (from Antwerp IV = **LNM** 476 (1975)).

Comment: Thanks, Prof.Elkies. I aksed a question about your paper. Would you please have a look ?

Comment: You're welcome.  I didn't notice your earlier question;
thanks for alerting me to it.